# Pro's and con's on using account information in error logs

Tags: android, error-handling

I was considering using the account manager service to retrieve a users email address whenever my application crashes on their mobile and include it in my error log. I would then email the user who encountered a bug to let them know that it was fixed in an update.

Would you consider this good or bad practice? Would you be happy to receive such notifications?

I am aware this may be considered an opinionated question, but are there are any precedents of this happening in other software?

Comment: If you do it, it better be in your privacy policy, and you should have users opt-out by default and a way to opt-in (not opt-in by default will opt-out).

Comment: This feels like an UX question rather than a programming related question

Answer (score 1):

as a developer sounds so nice.

as a user i will not install you software.